# Existence of $f$ such that $(f \circ f)(x)=-x^3+1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

> Is there any function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ has primitives on $\mathbb{R}$ and $$(f \circ f)(x)=-x^3+1$$for any $x$ real number?

I don't even know how to start solving this problem. Obviously, $f$ is bijective. if $f$ would have been differentiable one ideea would be to use $[F(f(x))]'=-x^3+1$ or something like this.

Comment: -1 What have you tried? We cannot help you if you don't show where you are stuck?

Comment: @stuartstevenson Sorry, I totally forgot

Comment: Careful. $[F(f(x))]' = f(f(x)) \cdot f'(x) = (1 - x^3)f'(x)$

Comment: Since $f$ is bijective (as you note) the thing to think about, is $f$ increasing or decreasing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Derivatives, defined over open intervals, by Darboux's theorem, are always Darboux functions. As you also pointed out, the function is bijective. Injective Darboux functions are always monotone (think about how you prove this for injective continuous functions, using the intermediate value theorem; it's the same proof). Hence, $f$ is either monotone increasing or decreasing.

But, in either case, one would expect $f \circ f$ to be increasing, and $x \mapsto 1 - x^3$ is (strictly) decreasing. This is a contradiction, hence no such $f$ can have a primitive.